# Download and View a PDF file in S3

Tags: html, amazon-s3, hyperlink, bucket

I have a pdf file in an s3 bucket. I want to link to it in HTML, but in two different areas. I want one of the links to be able to download the file directly and the other link to open the pdf in another browser tab.

I know I can specify the metadata of the file in the s3 bucket to do one or the other, but I haven't found a solution that will allow me to do both.

It seems like the s3 settings also overrides html tags like download.

Is there a solution that will allow me to both open that file with one HTML link and then download that same file with a different HTML link?